# IBM Domino Designer stuck on 'Sync with ODP...'

Tags: xpages, domino-designer-eclipse

I am using GitLab in combination with Sourcetree. Every time I want to commit something, I would go to my Domino Designer and right click the database, click Team Development and use 'Sync with ODP...'.

Most of the time everything works perfectly fine but sometimes the synchronization dialog pops up and just wont go away. In my Sourcetree I can see that some files are waiting to be commited but those files are not all.

So the dialog shows up, wont go away and says "Progress information" "Exporting..." and thats it.

There is no "use in background" button there and the 'cancel' button is disabled.

At this point the only thing I can do is to shut down the Designer using the task manager but the problem still wont go away even after restarting my computer and VirtualBox which I am working on (The designer runs on the VM). The only thing that changes: It sometimes gets stuck "later" in the progress.

I have read the designer hangs often due to automatic synchronization. In my case this feature is disabled.

Is there someone who can tell me what causes this problem and how I can fix it?
- Thank you in advance

(The synchronization is in progress for roughly four hours now, with no change)

Comment: I use Designer with Git (and SourceTree) almost daily, but these issues don't sound familiar. A couple of tips: use Designer 901 FP8 and Swiper v2. I do have automaticy import/ export of design elements turned off but syncing is (by default) linked to the 'build' process, so everytime I 'build' my application the changes will be exported to the on-disk project.

Comment: Thanks for the advice! Where can I find the v2 ?
I only found [this one](https://github.com/camac/Swiper) and am not sure if you refered to the version 1.0. **2** when you said v2

Comment: You're in the right repo. Download can be found here : https://github.com/camac/Swiper/releases

Answer (score 1):

Are you able to track it down to a specific design element? If there is a corruption in the DXL, the export to the ODP will probably fail. In Package Explorer you can use the "Open With..." right-click menu option to open as XML. Similarly, using the menu options to export as DXL might also highlight any corruption in DXL. Also, is the NSF local or on a server. If it's on a remote server, that may impact the performance of syncing to an ODP (which will be local).

Comment: Well, I didn't check for "corruption in the DXL" -> I am still fairly new to XPages and the Domino Designer. What I do know is that the ODP is local, as you already pointed out and the NSF is on a VM (Virtual Box) - No Idea if this could mean trouble for synchronization. Also, I cannot properly track it down to a specific design element, as the sync sometimes runs through without issues and sometimes is stuck at items, whereas the item it hangs up is rarely the same.

Comment: That sounds like either connectivity issues between local and VM. But another cause can be virus scanning software scanning either the data directory or the ODP folder. Obviously if you're updating lots of files and virus scanner decides to check recently changed files, there could be impact.

Answer (score 0):

We are using Domino Designer and Sourcetree in combination with Mercurial and Bitbucket for about a year now. 
We suffered a lot of difficulties: "hanging" sync, corrupted custom controls, missing files, lot of stress etc.

What I did find out: most of the syncing problems have something to do with the file IconNote in the resources. 
Sometimes the associated source contains another version of this resource, so it creates an IconNote.orig. Whenever this file exists, the syncing will go wrong. I guess that IconNote.orig isn't allowed in Resources and so the syncing stops without any warning(!) and often corrupted files.

It took me a very long time find out, but now I know: If IconNote exist in the Git, I delete it instantly! Syncing goes well aftwerwards.